# Command Function In Yargs

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I'm just trying to understand the command function used in the yargs module and the properties of the objects passed to it. In regards to the handler function used inside. Does argv represent the builder property from the object passed into the command function?

````
yargs.command({ //accepts an object as a parameter
    command: 'add', //name of command
    describe: 'Add a new note', //description,
    builder: {
        title: {
            describe: 'Note title',
            demandOption: true, //Title must be provided if true
            type: 'string' // needs to be a strin
        },
        body: {
            describe: 'Note body',
            demandOption: true, //Title must be provided if true
            type: 'string' // needs to be a strin
        }
    },
    handler: function (argv) {
        console.log('Title: ' + argv.title)
        console.log('Body: ' + argv.body)
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

This `argv` is what you passed when you run the `*.js` file.

This `argv` also consist two additional argument regarding the file location of this js file.

In this builder option you can modify how should this argument's property when they passed on.

Like you can modify if this argument is necessary or not ,type of this argument string or some other  like this.

Plis, in handler, there is a func which will run if any `arg` is there.you can decide what your program will do if those argument will passed on